# Collecting application trace on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, trace

I am working on a project that involves collecting kernel level and application level traces on a Raspberry pi. I was wondering if anyone has any application that might be suitable for this purpose? If not a rasberry pi. What way can i collect log trace on a linux system?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to get a variety of traces is to use the Perf tool. https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

A simple use would look like:

`perf record ./myapp`

and then run the following to see the results:

`perf report`

Brendan Gregg provides a lot of good info for perf here http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

You can also use tools like:

[strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

[ltrace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace)

[callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html)